# send scan job to Develop ineo 367 printer from nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tcp

I am developping a nodejs web app, one of the features the app should have is launching the scan (send scan job to the printer) from the web app and get back the result (pdf file contains the scanned documents) from the printer.

is there any hints or libraries could help ?
if no, is there a path where I can start to develop it from scratch ?

Thanks in advance.

I have searched for existing libraries but I didn't find a thing.